# How to make Facegrid Countplot hue bars side by side?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm plotting the blow graph with Facetgrid countplot. However, I cannot make the hue bars side by side.

[image]

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_df, row='Pclass', hue='Survived', size=2, aspect=2.5, sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.map(sns.countplot, 'Tclass', alpha=.6)
g.fig.suptitle('Distribution of Survival by Ticket Prefix and Ticket Class', fontsize=9.5, y=1.01)
g.set_xlabels('Ticket Prefix')
g.fig.text(0, .5, 'Ticket Prefix', va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=9.5)
g.add_legend()
```

So I tried using Factorplot, it failed as it didnt filter the Ticket Prefix (*Tclass*) that doesn't exist in that *Pclass*.

[image]

```
g = sns.factorplot(x='Tclass', data=titanic_df, row='Pclass', hue='Survived', kind='count', size=2, aspect=2.5, sharex=False, sharey=False)
```

What should I do? :(

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to make that in Facetgrid, but I did that with Matplotlib subplots manually. It's not smart, but at least I got what I want.

Please share with me smarter ways of achiving the same effect! Thanks!

[image]

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=[10,6])
g1 = sns.countplot(x='Tclass', hue='Survived', data=titanic_df[titanic_df.Pclass == 1], ax=ax1)
g2 = sns.countplot(x='Tclass', hue='Survived', data=titanic_df[titanic_df.Pclass == 2], ax=ax2)
g3 = sns.countplot(x='Tclass', hue='Survived', data=titanic_df[titanic_df.Pclass == 3], ax=ax3)

g1.set_title('Pclass = 1', fontsize=9.5, y=.85)
g2.set_title('Pclass = 2', fontsize=9.5, y=.85)
g3.set_title('Pclass = 3', fontsize=9.5, y=.85)
g1.set_xlabel(''); g2.set_xlabel(''); g3.set_xlabel('Ticket Prefix')
g1.set_ylabel(''); g2.set_ylabel('Frequency'); g3.set_ylabel('')
g1.legend(''); g3.legend('')
leg = g2.legend(fontsize='small', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
leg.set_title('Ticket Prefix', prop={'size':'small'})
fig.suptitle('Distribution of Survival by Ticket Prefix and Ticket Class', fontsize=9.5, y=.94)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `factorplot` will indeed use all possible `x` values in all its subplots. Hence the use of a `Facetgrid` may be required. The problem is that the `hue` of the `Facetgrid` will make each individual category plotted individually on the plot, hence the bars will overlapp. What you want is to use the `hue` of the `countplot` to obtain grouped bars. The problem is then that the `hue` argument is not correctly recognized by the map function. So you might write your own function to map, which takes the `hue` as argument.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(c=1, N=30):
    return pd.DataFrame({"class" : np.ones(N)*c,
                       "survived" : np.random.randint(0,2,size=N),
                       "ticket" : np.random.choice(list("ABCDE")[:c+2], size=N) })
df = f()
df = df.append(f(2))
df = df.append(f(3))    


def countplot(x, hue, **kwargs):
    data=kwargs.pop("data")
    order=np.unique(data["ticket"].values)
    sns.countplot(x, hue=hue, data=data,order=order,**kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='class',  size=2, aspect=2.5, sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.map_dataframe(countplot, 'ticket',hue='survived', alpha=.6, 
                palette=sns.color_palette(), )

g.fig.suptitle('Distribution of Survival')
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, left=0.1)
g.set_xlabels('Ticket Prefix')
g.add_legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`map_dataframe` is the trick that worked for me. You have to add current color pallete as it's argument.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_df, row='Pclass', size=2, aspect=2.5, sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.map_dataframe(sns.countplot, 'Tclass', hue='Survived', palette=sns.color_palette()).add_legend()
```